# Working with modals in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, bootstrap-modal

I've got this piece of code here

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" class="col-sm-4 portfolio-item">
         <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
```

However, I can't access {{item}} within the script tags. Is there a way I can insert id and type from outside the div tags? Sorry for the newbie question.

Here is the code for the controller:

```
.controller('listCtrl', function($scope, $modal, $log, $stateParams, items) {

    $scope.animationsEnabled = true;

    $scope.open = function(size) {

        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
            templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
            controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
            size: size,
            resolve: {
                item: function() {
                    return $scope.item;
                }
            }
        });

        modalInstance.result.then(function(selectedItem) {
            $scope.selected = selectedItem;
        }, function() {
            $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
        });
    };

    $scope.toggleAnimation = function() {
        $scope.animationsEnabled = !$scope.animationsEnabled;
    };

})

// Please note that $modalInstance represents a modal window (instance) dependency.
// It is not the same as the $modal service used above.

.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function($scope, $modalInstance, items) {

    $scope.items = items;
    $scope.selected = {
        items: $scope.items
    };

    $scope.ok = function() {
        $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
    };

    $scope.cancel = function() {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
})
```

Comment: Can't you achieve the same from controller ?

Comment: @Vineet How do you mean?

Comment: Show more code please or create a fiddle ?

Comment: @Vineet okay I will update the original post.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access `item` object in modal template because it's compiled in isolated scope child of the `$rootScope`, so there is not way for modal contents to inherit items.

What you want to do is to provide a base scope for the modal instance. Try this:

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
    scope: $scope, // <--- use this scope as the base for new scope
    animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
    templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
    controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
    size: size,
    resolve: {
        item: function() {
            return $scope.item;
        }
    }
});
```

In above snippet, modal service will create new child scope from the passed $scope, in which case modal scope will inherit prototypically items objects.

Comment: I think I get it. I tried your version however it didn't seem to work.

Comment: can you set up simple plunkr demo?